# KnockoutJS components with KendoUI chart only works for the last chart

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, kendo-ui

I have an Observable Array of items that creates components with a parameter.

Within each component, I use that parameter to query for data (through AJAX). I return that data into an Observable Array and use that Array as a data source for a KendoUI chart.

Example of list of created components with a parameter:

```
<csglist params="account:'08167526'"></csglist>
<hr>
<csglist params="account:'0873458'"></csglist>
<hr>
<csglist params="account:'0828337'"></csglist>
<hr>
<csglist params="account:'086778'"></csglist>
```

call that gets the data

```
        getCategory = function () {
            self.categoryChart([]);
            xhr_get(cont.publish + 'api/dbmain/getCategory', { 'id': params.account }).done(function (allData) {
                var mappedLogs = $.map(allData, function (item) { return new categoryData(item) });
                self.categoryChart(mappedLogs);
                buildChart();
            })
        }
function buildchart(){

    $(document).ready(createChart);
    $(document).bind("kendo:skinChange", createChart);
}
```

the create chart

```
 function createChart() {    
      $("#" + self.act() + "chart").kendoChart({
        dataSource: {
          data: ko.toJS(self.categoryChart)
            //, sort: { field: "category", dir: "asc" }
        },
        title: {
          text: self.type()
        },
        legend: {
          visible: true,
          position: "bottom"
        },
        seriesDefaults: {
          type: "bar",
          stack: true
        },
        series: [{
          field: "sales",
          name: "Current Sales",
          color: "#66110F"
        }, {
          field: "opp",
          name: "Opportunity",
          color: "#E65F5B"
        }],
        valueAxis: {
          //   max: 180,
          line: {
            visible: false
          },
          minorGridLines: {
            visible: true
          },
          visible: false
        },
        categoryAxis: {
          field: "category",
          majorGridLines: {
            visible: false
          }
        },
        tooltip: {
          visible: false,
          template: "#= series.name #: #= value #"
        }
      });
    }
```

But when the components are all created, only the last one has data.

Can anyone tell me why is this happening?

Comment: You should paste the code part you're populating the array, because it seems the problem is there.

Comment: You've made an unholy union of jQuery and Knockout. You need a binding handler. http://rniemeyer.github.io/knockout-kendo/dataviz/Chart.html

Comment: Roy J you are saying that since I am using this binding in an array I need to create a binding handle to apply it?

Comment: I am saying that all DOM manipulations (apart from some purely cosmetic things) belong in binding handlers. Certainly any DOM manipulations that involve your viewmodel do. The jQuery selector is a serious code smell in viewmodel code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when I changed the the buildChart = function to self.buildChart = function, it works!